# How can i make a post request to a rest api endpoint and the request to save my form in a view file in django?

Tags: python, django, python-requests, rest, python-requests-html

So i am trying to send a JSON file to a rest API endpoint and i am trying to use the requests library and it doesn't work.
Also in the function i have a return render to another page, because when i save a form i want also to send a request to the rest api to send an email and they only send emails via the endpoint.

```
   from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from Upload_Page import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from Upload_Page.forms import Upload_Document
from django.shortcuts import redirect
#from django.core.mail import send_mail
from Upload_Page.mail import mail_class
import requests
import json



def upload_doc(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Upload_Document(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()

      mail=mail_class()
      jsonmail=mail.createSimpleMail()
      requests.post("http://mail.internal.de1.bosch-iot-cloud.com:80/email",data=json.dumps(jsonmail))
      #send_mail('Title','Body','DigitalLibrary.BoschECC@bosch.com',['fixed-term.Razvan.Sabou@ro.bosch.com'],fail_silently=False)
      return render(request,'Upload_Page/upload_successful.html')
  
  else:
    
    form = Upload_Document(auto_id=True,label_suffix='')
  return render(request, 'Upload_Page/upload_page.html', {'form':form})
```

So this is the code, and i do not know why it doesn't send the post request, i checked the terminal to see what requests are made and the request from the requests it doesn't appear.

I've searched but i am new in django and Rest API and i didn't find the answer for my problem, if you need any more information i can provide it to you.

So thank you for the answer and have a good day.

Comment: are you sure the "requests" line is called? what if the form is not valid?

Comment: if the form is not valid i do not need to call the rest api request first i was saving the request in a reference and it didn't work, so i tried this and after i post it here @user7873949